# Why is this jquery so slow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jquery plugin which fixes the headers on a html table that I generate.  Unfortunately the performance of the plugin is very slow and I've narrowed it down to the following code:

```
var $tbl = $(this);  
var $tblhfixed = $tbl.find("thead");  
$tblhfixed.find("th").each(function ()    
    $(this).css("width", $(this).width());  
});
```

This is taking about 40 seconds on a table with 2,000 rows in ie.  Does anyone know why it's so slow and more importantly how can I make this faster?  I've tried many other plugins and this is the only one which works how I want it to.  Thanks for any help

Comment: Does the number of rows make a difference (Have you tested this)? You're only manipulating the table header. How many columns are there? You should use a filter rather than a find. http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/533451087251c952/9bb31c108c089c4f and http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/how-to-get-anything-you-want-part-2

Comment: What is `this`? What is the context? A http://jsfiddle.net would be great :)

Comment: Sorry, 'this' is a reference to the table I'm applying the plugin to

Comment: You could try: `$tblhfixed.find("th").width(function(i, val) { return val;});`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm chasing almost exactly the same problem and am suspecting jQuery's width() method which appears to be taking ~35 seconds for <6,000 elements.

Comment: @TomMorris did you find a solution? chasing the same problem :P

Comment: @thedayturns No, I ran out of time to investigate, but you can read more about my version of the problem in my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414150/jquery-width-method-performance

Comment: Take the table out of the document and add it to a document fragment > do all processing on table > add table back into document. Result > Layout and styling is only painted once by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you faced with the same problem that I had some time ago. It called a "Recalculate layout" or something.

Try to separate this script onto two loops, like this:

```
var $tbl = $(this);
var $tblhfixed = $tbl.find("thead");
var widths = [];

// 1.
$tblhfixed.find("th").each(function ()
    widths.push($(this).width());
});

// 2.
$tblhfixed.find("th").each(function (index, element)
    $(this).css("width", widths[index]);
});
```

First one will calculate all the widths. Second one will apply them to TH's

**UPD:**
You may increase performance by placing this code between 1. and 2.:

```
$tblhfixed.hide();
```

and show it again after 2.:

```
$tblhfixed.show();
```

Comment: That really helped me, although I do not fully understand why and really my code still works rather slow - definitely faster than before, but still slow.

Answer (score 1):

the culprit is probably the `.each`.

The reason is that when you iterate using `.each`instead of a normal loop, you call a function for each iteration. a function call has a pretty big overhead in this case, since a new callstack has to be created for each iteration.

To make it faster change

```
$tblhfixed.find("th").each(function ()    
    $(this).css("width", $(this).width());  
});
```

to

```
var elms = $tblhfixed.find("th");
for(var i=0, elm;elm = elms[i];i++) {
    elm.css("width", elm.width());  
}
```

Comment: though true, i think the `.each()` overhead is negligible - compared to the repeated calls to `$(this)`

Comment: Actually the .each overhead is quite massive, try to look here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/6

Comment: `width()` is not the fastest function in the universe too, IIRC, so I'd cache that call too.

Answer (score 1):

you should not repeat `$(this)` inside your function passed into `.each()`. wrapping an element has non-trivial overhead, which is not ok when you have 20k elements. you want to eliminate as much work as possible inside the `.each()` call, or eliminate it altogether.

Also, why query `find()` twice, when you can do this instead, which should give you the same results:

```
$ths = $('table thead th'); //or tableid, or something
$ths.css('width', $ths.width());
```

Comment: Why do you set the `th` width to the `table` width? This is not what the OP's code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use `find()` only when you need to pass through all nested nodes. Right here you can use `children()`.

Second, each time `$(this)` creates new instance of jQuery object, while you can create it once:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Each time `$(this).width()` is recalculated. Make sure that you need it to be recalculated. Or do:

```
var tableWidth = $this.width();
```

And third, according to @Martin Jespersen, each iteration the `function` object is created.

Also you don't need jQuery here at all. You can access DOM directly:

```
var tableWidth = ...; // get the table width the way you want
var thead = this.tHead;
var thRow = thead.rows[0];
for (var i = 0; i < thRow.length; ++i) {
  thRow.cells[i].style.width = tableWidth + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it appears that $.width() is 99 times slower than the native get(0).clientWidth, check out this test: http://jsperf.com/jq-width-vs-client-width